# Why method persist of PersistentActor doesn't return a Future?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a theoretical question. Recently I wrote this code:

```
class Account extends PersistentActor {
    def receiveCommand = {
        case Block(id, amount) => persist(Block(id, amount)){
            case Block(id, amount) =>
                persist(RevertBlock(id, s"Id ${id} already in processing", 
                  balance + amount))(_.revert())
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

It looks bad. Why method `persist` takes callback as 2nd argument instead return a Future?

Comment: With a Future, I believe you could only persist one event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deal in context. The sender() inside the callback is always valid, it not be true for futures.